# Подключение GetComponent<Renderer>()

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Прохожу уроки по Unity и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
private Renderer renders;

void Start()
{
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    renders = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if (isLooping)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);

            if (child.renderer != null)
            {
                backgroundPart.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В последнем if на 'renderer' вылазит ошибка: Component.renderer является устаревшим, используйте GetComponent(), сделал по аналогии с rigidbody2D, но если заменить 'renderer' не 'renders' тогда появляется другая ошибка: Transform не содержит определения для renders. В чем может быть причина?
До: http://prntscr.com/l9qe51
После: http://prntscr.com/l9qe9f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `GetComponent<T>()` - это метод класса `MonoBehaviour`. Он ищет на объекте, на котором висит, указанный вместо T класс.

Другими словами, в вашем случае вызывая `renders = GetComponent<Renderer>();` - вы ищите на текущем объекте компонент Renderer и назначаете его в приватную переменную `renders`.

После этого вы начинаете в цикле перебирать все дочерние объекты. Вы получаете компонент `Transform` объекта в `Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);` после чего спрашиваете `if (child.renderer != null)`. Т.е. вы спрашиваете у класса Transform не является ли его публичное поле renderer пустым.

Это устаревший код, который будет скоро выпилен и вам советуют использовать вместо него `GetComponent<T>()`. В вашем случае это бы выглядело следующим образом:

```
Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);
var childRenderer = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
if (childRenderer  != null)
{
    backgroundPart.Add(child);
}
```

т.е. у каждого дочернего объекта вы пытаетесь через метод GetComponent() найти `Renderer`, если результат не равен null - объект добавляется в список.